# Warning the user about multiple external addresses in an Outlook on-send add-in?

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, email-client

A requirement has arisen in our organisation to be able to warn users when they attempt to send an email containing multiple external recipients in the `To:` field of Outlook (instead of the `Bcc:` field).

To me it looks like this should be possible using an "on-send" Outlook add-in, but although I have reviewed [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows) regarding this, I'm having trouble understanding how I would modify the provided code examples to achieve this.

Is this actually possible and if so how would I do it?

Comment: Hi, I have posted a code snippet with which you can leverage on
function checkToListAndShowWarningsAppropriately() {
  var emailItem = Office.context.mailbox.item;
  var toList = emailItem.to;
  for (var i = 0; i < toList.length; i++) {
    var toRecipentType = toList[i].recipientType;
    console.log(toRecipentType);
    if (toRecipentType == "externalUser") {
      emailItem.notificationMessages.addAsync("information", {
        type: "informationalMessage",
        message: "Found an external user in the To List",
        icon: "iconid",
        persistent: false      }); }}}

Comment: And kindly have a look at these https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.notificationmessages?view=outlook-js-preview and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailboxenums.recipienttype?view=outlook-js-preview for better understanding.

Comment: We actually need to count the number of external addresses and only take action if the count is greater than one. With the notification messages it seems like only passive notifications are possible? Ideally we'd like the user to actively confirm that they still want to send the message, for example via a dialog box with two buttons "Don't Send" (the default) and "Send Anyway".

Comment: Instead of notifications, you can use "Office Dialog API" [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins]. We have provided the minimum code, and you can have a counter on no. of external users and show the dialog appropriately. Please let us know if you need any other info.